# Updating same table with reference to another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update my tableA with the sum of values in tableB, but with grouping according to a date in tableA.

This is the nearest I can get but no cigar:

```
update tableA set C1Count = (
    select val from (
        select  a.prodind, sum(b.val) as val from tableA a , tableB b
        where b.date BETWEEN a.ActStartC1 and a.ActFinC1
        group by a.prodind) tmp_tbl
    )
    where tableA.prodind = tmp_table.prodind
)
```

Comment: could we see the relevant structure of your tables?

Comment: share your data and expected output it will helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example of table updating from one to other table in mysql

```
 UPDATE tableB
    INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.name = tableA.name
    SET tableB.value = IF(tableA.value > 0, tableA.value, tableB.value)
    WHERE tableA.name = 'Joe'
```

For your case i think below should work

```
update tableA a
inner join (
        select  a.prodind, sum(b.val) as val from tableA a , tableB b
        where b.date BETWEEN a.ActStartC1 and a.ActFinC1
        group by a.prodind
        ) tmp_tbl
        on a.prodind=tmp_table.prodind
set a.C1Count=val
```

But i think you should have to mention join explicitly between tableA and tableB

Comment: Zaynul, you are the man! That works perfectly, thank you very much. Jamie.